# Looking to create a subquery that displays only one column MYSQL

Tags: mysql, subquery, groupwise-maximum

This database is for a book loan system. Where if a student takes a copy of a book the system accepts there student number and gives them a return date for the book. These are the two tables I am using

loan table:

```
 CREATE TABLE loan (
    `code` INT NOT NULL,
    `no` INT NOT NULL,
    taken DATE NOT NULL,
    due DATE NOT NULL,
    `return` DATE NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pri_loan PRIMARY KEY (taken),
    CONSTRAINT for_loan 
        FOREIGN KEY (`code`) REFERENCES copy (`code`),
        FOREIGN KEY (`no`) REFERENCES student (`no`));
```

student table:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
`no` INT NOT NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
school CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
embargo BIT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pri_student PRIMARY KEY (`no`));
```

Firstly I am looking to calculate the latest due date for a book copy (it will bring up the code for the book and when the latest due date for that book is)
 which I have done by using this code which worked perfectly

```
SELECT `code`, max(due)
FROM loan
    GROUP BY `code`
```

Now I want to modify this query so that it fetches the latest due dates for each book but will only display the student number (`no`) that has the book. To do this I need to use a sub query which I know very little about as I am only starting to use MySQL. Basically im unsure how to create this sub query and I am wondering if someone can help me out and also explain it not just show me the code.

Comment: There are some design issues you could look at - I don't think taken is a good candidate for a primary key, you could use descriptive names like taken_date instead of taken , studentid instead of no in the loan table. And your current query doesn't take into account returns. Also how to you identify if a library has more than 1 copy of a book?

Comment: Why would you need the max(due_date) surely just checking  where return is null would give you all those not yet returned?

Comment: Basically this is just a dummy database and the field names dont matter too much atm as I said im only learning how to use MySQL. In terms of the books there is more than one of each book & in the loan table you can see how many of each book are already loaned out (theres only a couple of each) how ever that first query im talking about fetches the latest due date of each book that is already loaned out eg:(book1 has been loaned to student 2001 and it has the latest due date so this is the row that is being returned) im just looking to create a sub query so the table only shows student number

Comment: The design issues I will work on in the future, im just looking to practice different functions that a MySQL database can carry out. Im not really looking to create a proper database that would work perfectly if I was to implement it into an actual library.

Comment: I added the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag. This type of question has been answered many times. Follow the tag for examples.

Comment: While you are still learning, it's important to think about your table structures.  How you design your tables affect what information you can retrieve from the same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `HAVING` syntax:

```
SELECT
    `no` as student
FROM
    `loan`
GROUP BY
    `code`
HAVING
    DATETIME(`due`) = MAX(DATETIME(`due`));
```

`HAVING` lets you add a condition to a `SELECT` statement that references and filters by the available values (including selected columns and their final values, which can be really handy if you're doing calculations).

See here for more info: https://www.guru99.com/group-by.html

Comment: Thanks for the info that actually really helps. I can understand what you mean with the having statement. However when I run this query it returns no results can you possibly tell we what each part of this is doing to help me understand it a bit better

Comment: Sure thing. I actually just changed a couple things, and I may have my syntax a little bit incorrect (as there isn't a MySQL Fiddle site I trust to run correctly, I can't actually test the query to make sure it runs like it should). Basically, for `HAVING`, you need to select the value you want to compare, and then reference it in the `HAVING` call. This sort of thing depends a lot on exactly where in the query you're putting your subquery, and how you're accessing the data.

Comment: Edited again to include the group by, since in thinking on it that's probably also required in this case. Also, in the `HAVING` statement at the end, I cast the dueDate to a dateTime, so that MySQL can more accurately compare the values (since it's kind of picky about how you use numerical operators with datetime information).