# Error Code:1242 Subquery returns more than one row

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-error-1242

Basically im new to MySQL and was just trying to get the hang of sub-queries. Im looking to create a query which will calculate the max due date for an item based on the items id. However once it finds the max due date i want it to only display the items name in the results. The code im looking to use a sub-query is:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, max(due) FROM loan WHERE `name` =
(SELECT `name` FROM loan) ORDER BY `name`
```

I keep getting error 1242 and i dont know why. i know the answer is probably simple but as i mentioned im really new at this.

Comment: `WHERE name = (SELECT name FROM loan)` does not make any sense in this context, when you are already getting data from the same table. You possibly need `group by name`

Comment: Remarkably similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992795/looking-to-create-a-subquery-that-displays-only-one-column-mysql are you guys classmates? The linked question is better.